# How do I get access to Weblogic's properties in Java code

Tags: properties, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

Is it possible in Java code (ejb) to read (some of) Weblogic's internal configuration properties, like:

Domain name, Domain home, Admin Server name, Port number, Server name, Host name, Config version, Weblogic acount name, etc.?

And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jmx/accessWLS.html#wp1111297) is an example - The principle is the same whether you're in an EJB module or not.